# Android C++ framebuffer ioctl, only with root?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to use ioctl in android native C++ code. I want to know is it possible to use on non rooted devices?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, anything that gives you access to the frame buffer is going to be off-limits to unprivileged apps, for security reasons (e.g. phishing schemes).

Not all devices have linear frame buffers, and many devices prefer hardware overlays over framebuffer blits, so whatever you have in mind may not work, and probably won't be portable even if it does.